# How to hide tkinter root window and show my image?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have this code where I click the button and tkinter window shows an image along with a tk root window.
I tried using root.withdraw() however this just ends up creating the tkinter root window and does not display my image.. Would need help in showing the image only and hiding the tkinter root window as well

```
def on_click_button():
    global stage
    stage == 'Menu'
    root = tk.Toplevel()
    photoImageObj = tk.PhotoImage(file="showimg.png")             
    lab = tk.Label(root, image=photoImageObj).pack()
    root.withdraw()
    root.mainloop()
    print('You clicked samsung note 20')
```

Comment: You're creating _two_ windows: a `Toplevel` and an implicit root (assuming you haven't created a root window prior to this function). Are you aware of that?

Comment: I have tried creating a `toplevel root 'root = tk.Toplevel()'` before running the button and the same issue still happens. I also need the `Toplevel` root to run the tkinter window. I am very new to tkinter so not too sure what's the implicit root I am creating and would like to remove the extra window if possible, thanks for the help!

Comment: If you haven't created an instance of `Tk`, then creating a `Toplevel` will implicitly create one for you, resulting in two windows. Since you didn't provide a complete [mcve] it's impossible for us to know if you've already created an instance of `Tk` before calling this function. So, is your code somewhere doing `something = Tk()`?

Comment: ah I have a function `# creates a window
def create_window():
    window = tk.Toplevel(root)`
and I have `root = tk.Tk()` for other buttons as well, however I think this does not conflict with the samsung note 20 button. Please correct me if I am wrong though. Thanks for the help!

Comment: edit under other clickable buttons I have `root = tk.Tk()
    w = tk.Label(root, text=('hello'))
    w.pack()
    w.config(width=0, height=0)
    w.config(font=("Courier", 30))
    root.mainloop()`  as well, but not sure if these are causing the problems as I am currently trying to create a button click event that opens the tkinter window with images i need to show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tkinter sets the `master` attribute of a widget to be a reference to the master for that widget. Since you didn't explicitly set the master for the instance of `Toplevel`, `master` will be the root window. So, *in this specific case* you can call `withdraw` on `root.master`:

```
root.master.withdraw()
```

Personally, I would recommend against naming your `Toplevel` "root" since it's not the true root window. It makes the code a bit harder to understand since a true root window will not have a master.

You will want to provide a mechanism for showing the root window at some point, since withdrawing it will keep it alive but not visible.

Comment: ah great thanks! The `root.master.withdraw()` helps to hide the tkinter root, however this caused me to not be able to close the window back to the menu in the previous window. Guess for now my best solution is to keep the tkinter root to close the window.

Comment: @Codenoob: if you aren't using the root window for anything else, why don't you put your image in it?

Comment: not too sure how to input the image into the root window... That's a very smart suggestion! Do i let root = tk.Label(root, image=photoImageObj).pack()?

Comment: @Codenoob: you add it to the root window exactly the same as you are adding it to `Toplevel`.